# Click events blocked when using float in IE, Chrome and Firefox

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to understand why the following example does not support clicking of the button in Chrome 25.0 or Firefox 18.  It works in IE 9/10.

I feel as though I'm missing something very basic.  Z-Index?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0px;
            overflow: hidden;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .top {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
            background: gold;
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align: middle;
            z-index: 1;
        }
        .left {
            float: left;
            height: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 80%;
        }

        .right {
            float: right;
            height: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            right: 0;
            top: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="top">
        <button id="btn" onclick="alert('hello')">Click Me!</button>
    </div>
    <div class="left">
        left
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        right
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The z-index property only works on positioned elements, so add something like `position:relative;` to your #top div.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/gcfjD/)**

An alternative method is to apply `pointer-events:none;` to your #left div so that the click passes through to the element below it.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/gcfjD/1/)**

Comment: Thanks.  Any idea why IE would have a different behavior or is the answer obvious?

Comment: My knee-jerk reaction is to say that IE is a turd and never use that as a yardstick to measure how well any code works.